# Testing for "Invalid character in a Base-64 string"

Tags: c#, .net, base64, html-encode

I've been seeing the "Invalid character in a Base-64 string" error quite a bit in my application log.  I've read up on a bunch of different reasons why it may come up and some potential fixes.  The problem is that I cannot reproduce the error locally.

I believe that it is coming up on the `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` call but I'm not exactly sure.

Here is my StackTrace from the error:

```
at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)     
at System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString)     
at System.Web.UI.Util.DeserializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter formatter, String serializedState)     
at System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load()
```

The error is happening on an email submission form; user enters name, email address and message and it is sent to per-specified email address via SMTP.

I'm looking for some ways that I can try and force this error to happen so I can work on fixing it.

The code segment is as follows:

```
    var emailMessage = new MailMessage();
    emailMessage.From = new MailAddress(emailAddress, name);
    emailMessage.Subject = "Subject";
    emailMessage.Body = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(message);
    emailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(contactEmailAddress, contactName));
    var smtpClient = new SmtpClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPServer"]);
    smtpClient.Send(emailMessage);
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't think the code segment really added anything.  It's in there now.

Comment: Have you tried some weird characters from outside the usual ASCII charset? See [BodyEncoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.bodyencoding.aspx)

Comment: For example `string message = new string(new char[] {'\u2190', '\u2191', '\u2192', '\u2193'});`

Comment: Tried that, and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Like any good standard, Base64 has many too choose from.  This [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table) lists the common variants, several of these will be rejected by the .NET method.  The troublesome ones are the characters for index 63 and 64, the .NET encoder uses + and /.  And requires padding, but that generates another exception.

You'll need to improve your error logging to really know what you are dealing with.